# how can I link with gcc without moving things in a .text section

Tags: gcc, ld, sections

I'm trying to make an executable out of two files:

- `vm.o`, which contains a bunch of non-relocatable functions,
- `launcher.c`, which has a `main` function that starts my vm.

`vm.o` is an elf32 file, with a .text section of code that expects to be loaded at `0x401000`, as shown by `objdump -x vm.o`.

```
...
SYMBOL TABLE:
00401000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00401000 g       .text  00000000 _binary_vm_o_start
....
```

I'm running gcc like this:

```
gcc -no-pie -m32 -o vm vm.o loader.c -ldl
```

But the generated file ignores the positions specified in vm.o. If I do

```
gcc -no-pie -m32 -o vm vm.o loader.c -ldl -Ttext 0x401000
```

I get close, but `_start` is put at `0x401000` and my `vm.o` is put at `0x4010fb`.

Is there a simple way to tell gcc to put the .text section of `vm.o` in the desired position? I know a way of doing this with ld, but I'd rather use gcc to link.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround that, while not exactly the same, works very well. I can just rename my .text section in vm.o (so that it does not get merged with the other .text ones), and then make gcc put that particular section at the desired position:

```
# change the name of .text section to .vm
objcopy --rename-section .text=.vm,contents,alloc,load,code vm.o vm-temp.o

# compile setting .vm to 0x401000 (no-pie means no position-independent code)
gcc -no-pie -m32 -o vm vm-temp.o loader.c -Wl,--section-start=.vm=0x401000 -ldl
```

note that the `-T` in gcc only works for changing the address of .text but doesn't for other sections.